# How to recursively search header files

Tags: c++

I tried to use vim to write a qt code, but encountered the problem of header file inclusion, this is my code

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My header file search path is

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Users/luxiangyun/Qt/6.2.3/macos/lib
 /Users/luxiangyun/Qt/6.2.3/macos/include
 .
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/13.1.6/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
```

The location of this header file QApplication is `/Users/luxiangyun/Qt/6.2.3/macos/lib/QtWidgets.framework/Versions/A/Headers`

we can see that the header file I want is under the directory where the compiler looks for the path, So is there a way to recursively find header files?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible. Also consider this: imaging it was possible and you #include 'thing.h' but theres two of them in different folders (which is legal), which one should it use?

Comment: @Borgleader I just tried the situation you mentioned, it is really interesting, I will get an error of use of undeclared identifier, if I specify this header file precisely, this error will be eliminated again

Comment: If you mean with an `#include` directive, the answer is no, you have to specify the path below an include (-I) root.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738956/can-i-search-directory-and-subdirectories-for-header-files